# Alternative fingering for high B-flat to D, on the oboe

Tags: technique, fingering, oboe

Does anybody know of an alternative way to finger high B-flat to D on the oboe?

In Malcom Arnold's *Divertimento for Flute, Oboe, and Clarinet*, there is a vivace 16th note section alternating between B-flat and D.  I cannot this play cleanly with normal fingerings.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

The standard B flat fingering along with the third D fingering on this list http://www.wfg.woodwind.org/oboe/ob_alt_3.html might work for you, it at least makes it so you only have to move one finger on each hand.

You've probably already looked there though, but if not, you might find some other workable combinations.

Comment: Every instrument has some ugly note transitions somewhere :-( .  A lot of practice techniques such as "galumph" , aka playing first as dotted eighth-sixteenth and then sixteenth-dotted-eighth thru the note sequence, will help.